# Bijection of minimal sufficient statistics

Tags: statistics, functions, mathematical-modeling

If $T_1(X)$ and $T_2(X)$ are minimal sufficient statistics, does there (always) exist a bijective function g, s.t. $T_1(X)=T_2(X)$?

I think that this may be true, as they both have the minimal information about the statistical model s.t. it is sufficient. Therefore, should contain the same number of data points, which are about the same information.

Comment: A minimal sufficient statistic is a function of any other sufficient statistic, so if each is a function of the other then these functions must be bijections